# Recovering from `error symbol grub_is_lockdown not found` on a cloud host

Tags: boot, server, grub2, remote-access

I rent a bare-metal server which, following a recent Proxmox update, started sporadically throwing errors at boot -- specifically `error symbol grub_is_lockdown not found`. Proxmox is built on Ubuntu, so I was able to find some guidance about this, but most of it boils down to either:

- This happened during initial install, so just use a different Rufus setting and try again; or
- The missing symbol is slightly different

Best as I can tell, this was caused by my choice to keep a grub configuration as it already existed on the host, rather than using the package maintainer's version. As I'd never manually changed any grub configs, I assumed it had some options which made it play nicer with my hosting provider's infra, so I chose to keep the existing version. This was apparently the wrong choice.

I now have SSH access to the host which is booted into a rescue partition, but I'm not experienced in troubleshooting grub issues. What are some good steps to diagnose and patch this?

I'll be happy to post any grub configs if that's necessary to diagnose this issue.

In a perfect world, I'd like to just get this host back up and running. It's fortunately just a hobby box, but rebuilding it from VM images would still be a hassle I'd prefer to avoid if possible